# Show that G is a group, if G is finite, the operation is associative, and cancellation law holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a non-empty finite set with an associative binary operation so that cancellation law holds, i.e. $ab=ac$ or $ba=ca$ implies $b=c$, for any choices of $a,b,c$ in $G$. Assume that there is an identity element $e$ in $G$. Show that $G$ is a group.

**Proof**: To show $G$ is a group, conditions must hold. Suppose that $ab=ac$, then $b=eb=(a^{-1}a)b
=a^{-1}(ab)=a^{-1}(ac)
=(a^{-1}a)c=ec=c$. So left cancellation holds in $G$.

2) Suppose $ba=ca$, then $b=be=b(aa^{-1})
=(ba)a^{-1}=(ca)a^{-1}
=c(aa^{-1})=ce=c$. So right cancellation holds in $G$.

3) If $a$ exists in $G$ then $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=e$, where $a$ is an inverse of $a^{-1}$. Since inverses are unique, $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$.

4) Let $x$ be the inverse of $ab$. Then $(ab)x=e$. By associativity we have $a(bx)=aa^{-1}$. Through left cancellation we have 
$bx=a^{-1}bx=ea^{-1}=b(b^{-1}a^{-1})$ and $x=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Thus $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. So all conditions hold, $G$ is a group.

Is this proof correct? I know to show $G$ is a group these conditions have to be met. This is all I have to show right?

Comment: You already have an associative binary operation with an identity, and you are told that the cancellation law applies. You need to show that this implies that every element has an inverse - you will need to use the fact you are given that the set is finite, which you have not used in your proof.

Comment: Note - the non-negative integers under addition are an infinite set which has an associative binary operation, identity (zero) and cancellation, but only the identity has an inverse.

Comment: @Ale Tolcachier, your edit of the title (nr.7 in the list) has completely changed OP's original one (or at least up to rev.6) and made it trivially true.

Comment: Uh, You're right. I was totally wrong

Answer (score 17):

Another proof makes use of the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). Fix $a \in G$, and consider the map
$$
f : G \to G, \qquad x \mapsto a x.
$$
Since $G$ is cancellative, the map is injective, hence surjective because $G$ is finite, so that there is $b \in G$ such that $e = f(b) = a b$.

Similarly, there is $c \in G$ such that $c a = e$.

Thus $$c = c e = c (a b) = (c a) b = e b = b,$$ and $b = c$ is the required inverse of $a$.

---

You need not assume that there is an identity, but can prove that one exists.

First show, with the arguments above, that any element $z$ of $G$ can be written in the form $z = x a$, for some $x \in G$. Then show that there is $s \in G$ such that $a s = a$. Now $$z s = x a s = x a = z, \quad\text{for all $z \in G$,}$$ so $s$ is a right identity. Similarly there is a left identity $t$ such that $$t z = z,\quad \text{for all $z \in G$,}$$ and finally $$t = t s = s$$ is *the* identity.

Comment: Thank you. Seeing it this way was very helpful as well

Comment: @RuthGutierrez, you're welcome.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I don't quite understand the proof for identity. I thought it should be z = ax? why is it z = xa?

Answer (score 9):

You *know* that cancellation holds in $G$, it's a hypothesis, so you have not to prove it. And, most important, you can't use inverses of elements without first proving they exist, which is exactly what you have to do.

Consider an element $a\in G$ and the map $f_a\colon G\to G$ defined by
$$
f(x)=ax
$$
This map is injective. *Why?*

This map is also surjective, because of an important hypothesis you have. *Which one?*

Now, what can you say about the element $x$ such that $f_{a}(x)=e$? *It is…*

Next, consider the map $g_{a}\colon G\to G$ defined by $g_{a}(x)=xa$. Repeat the reasoning to conclude.

Answer (score 6):

No, you seem to be assuming things like the inverse would exist in your proof, which is the only thing you really need to prove (the other 3 conditions in the definition of a group are given to you).

So choose $a\in G$, and consider the set
$$
\{a, a^2, a^3, \ldots \} \subset G
$$
Since $G$ is finite, this set is finite, and so there exist $a^i, a^j$ such that $i>j$ and
$$
a^i = a^j
$$
Now consider $f = a^{i-j}$, then
$$
fa^j = a^i = a^j = ea^j \Rightarrow f = e
$$
Hence, if $b = a^{i-j-1}$, then
$$
ab = e = ba
$$
and hence $b = a^{-1} \in G$

Comment: So just showing that the identity and inverse exist in G then this shows that G is a group?

Comment: You are already given an identity, and you are already given closure (because it is a binary operation), and associativity. The only thing left is the inverses.

Comment: Oh ok which showed that a^-1 exists in G.

Comment: thank you this was very helpful

Comment: I noticed you find an identity $e_x$ for a given $x\in G$. I would like to ask why is this identity a "general" identity, that is, why is $e_xg=ge_x=g$ true for all $g\in G$?

Comment: @rgm It is because $G$ has an identity $e$, and the cancellation laws hold. So if $e_xx = x = ex$, then $e_x = e$ must hold.

Comment: Brilliant! I just knew there had to be a way to do this [without the concepts of 'injective' or 'surjective'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830620/140308).

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't understand you constantly claiming that "You are already given an identity", how ? I mean the binary operation does not have to have an identity element. The existence of the identity element of a binary operation is an additional property of the operation.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: As per the OP's question, an identity is a given.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thank for pointing out, I thought mine and OP's question were the same after reading the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The cancellation laws imply that left and right multiplication maps by a given $a\in G$ (say $l_a$ and $r_a$, respectively) are injective and hence (finiteness of $G$, see "pigeonhole principle") both are bijections on $G$. By the associativity, then, $l_al_b=l_{ab}$ and $r_ar_b=r_{ba}, \forall a,b\in G$, and hence (closure) $L:=\{l_a,a\in G\}\le\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ and $R:=\{r_a,a\in G\}\le\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Therefore, $\exists e_l,e_r\in G$ such that $l_{e_l}=r_{e_r}=Id_G$ or, equivalently, $e_lg=ge_r=g, \forall g\in G$; as a particular case, $g=e_l$ and left cancellation imply $e_l=e_r=:e$ (same conclusion by assuming $g=e_r$ and right cancellation), so we finally get that $\exists e\in G$ such that $eg=ge=g, \forall g\in G$ (and hence the existence of the identity needs not to be assumed, but can be gotten from the finiteness and the cancellation laws).

About the inverses, note that by the surjectivity of $l_a$ and $r_a$ (for every $a\in G$), $\exists a_l,a_r\in G$ such that $e=l_a(a_r)=r_a(a_l)$. Now:

\begin{alignat}{1}
e=aa_r &\Rightarrow a_r=a_re=a_raa_r \\
&\Rightarrow a_ra=e \\
&\Rightarrow a_ra=aa_r \\
&\Rightarrow a_ra=a_la \\
&\Rightarrow a_r=a_l=:a^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}

and hence left and right inverses exist and coincide for every $a\in G$. Therefore, $G$ is indeed a group.