# Does cancellation property imply invertibility?

Tags: group-theory

I have no problem seeing how having an inverse implies cancellation property, but I've problems proving (or even seeing why) the converse must be also true. Can you please suggest a way to approach this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Cancellation property does not imply existence of inverse element. Consider the additive monoid $(\Bbb{N},+)$. (We wiil assume that $\Bbb{N}$ contains 0.) Then $(\Bbb{N},+)$ satisfies associativity and cancellation property but all elements except 0 have no inverse element.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that cancellation works because there is an inverse, but the inverse element is not nessesarily part of the set and that's what invertability is?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn I do not think your explanation is correct in full detail. Every non-zero element of N has no inverse, and so we do not know how to talk about what the inverse of 1 is, for example. In my example, it should be −1, but it may not be obvious for more complex structure.

Comment: However, I *guess* every monoid with cancellation property can be extended to a group. It really holds if we assume the monoid is abelian. I do not know my guess really holds and I have no time to check it.

Answer (score 2):

However, if you require the set to be finite, then you do get invertibility (this is a common way to show that $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ is a field).

Comment: Brilliant! I just knew there had to be a way to do this [without the concepts of 'injective' or 'surjective'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830620/140308).